# In Ruby, how do I combine sleep with gets? I want to wait for user response for 1 min, otherwise continue

Tags: ruby, timer, sleep, gets

I'm running a loop, in which I wait for a user response using the "gets.chomp" command.
How can I combine that with a sleep/timer command?

For example. I want it to wait 1 min for the user to enter a word, otherwise it would continue back to the loop.

Comment: Timeout did work for me.  However, I also found this other way to accomplish this task:

require 'Win32API'

@@kbhit = Win32API.new("msvcrt", "_kbhit", [], 'I')

for i in 0..60
unless @@kbhit.call.zero?
a = gets()
break
end
sleep 1
end
if i==60
puts "..."
end

Comment: Then why did you mark something as an accepted answer?

Comment: because it was an elegant solution that I tried and works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Timeout method above is probably the most elegant way of solving this problem.  Another solution that is available in most languages is using [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001406).  You pass a list of file descriptors to monitor and an optional timeout.  The code is much less concise:

```
ready_fds = select [ $stdin ], [], [], 10
puts ready_fds.first.first.gets unless ready_fds.nil?
```

Answer (score 5):

You should look at Ruby's [`Timeout`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/timeout/1.9.2/frames).

From the docs:

```
require 'timeout'
status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
  # Something that should be interrupted if it takes too much time...
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get Timeout to work.  My loop includes a system call, and I was reading that the Timeout module sometimes seems to have problems with that.

Comment: Well, I use Timeout to wrap Net::HTTP and Open::URI calls, which both make system calls, and those seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def gets_or_timeout(to)
 # Use thread and time limit to wait for a key or refresh after time if no key is hit.
 t=Thread.new{ print "\n> "; gets}
 t.join(to) #wait for end or number of seconds
 t.kill
end

...
gets_or_timeout(60)
...
```